# inner product complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inner-products

Good day, please help with this exercise, I am very confused, especially for the positivity and conjugate conditions.

Let $ V =C([0,1])$, the complex space of the continuous functions : $[0,1] \to \mathbb C$.

Show that the following is an inner product :

$\langle x, y\rangle  = \int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$.

Comment: what confuses you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$. You need to verify the [axioms of inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). The *conjugate symmetry* and *linearity* are really easy. The *semi-positive-definiteness* $\langle f,f\rangle\geq0$ is straightforward too. The only delicate point is to verify that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ implies $f=0$:

Assume that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ and that $f\neq0$ to get a contradiction. As $f\neq0$ there is some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq0$. As $f$ is continuous there must exist a closed interval $I$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I$. This implies that $K:=\min_{x\in I}|f(x)|>0$ (which makes sense by the continuity of $|f|$), which leads to the contradiction
$$
\langle f,f\rangle=\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\geq\int_I|f(x)|^2dx\geq K^2|I|>0.
$$

Comment: yes, thanks, but the semi-positive definitess, why is not negative? Must I use $f*\bar{f}=u^{2}+v^{2}$?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$ then yes, you could justify it like that. However, there is no need to express $f=u+iv$; just notice that $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$ for any complex number $z$. The modulus of a complex number is always non-negative so $f(x)\overline{f(x)}=|f(x)|^2$ is as well.